# Is it possible to extend your Origin gametime?

Tags: origin

Is there a way to get more "gametime" on a specific game in Origin after it runs out? Or a way to extend one's "gametime" before running out?

Comment: If my answer has solved your question, please use the tick underneath the downvote arrow.

Comment: Had to wait a certain time , then forgot. Sorry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### No, you CANNOT extend your Origin<sup>TM</sup> Game Time<sup>TM</sup> counters.

Game time is designed to be a timed demo. It's basically, "try before you buy". Extending is not possible due to the way the system works and how timed data is stored.
There isn't any method to extend it because it is a timed demo of a full game.

**Alternatively, you can do what the system's trying to achieve, which is to buy the game.**
With this system, they're hoping that you're invested into the game by the end of the two hours, to the point where you'll want to continue progress, thus buy the game.

---

> Couldn't they just do a time extender?

That'd the pointless.. **It is a timed demo. Not some subscription-based model placed on a game that can normally be purchased for a one-time fee.**

*I'd dread to see what happens if Minecraft had adopted a subscription-based model.*

Comment: Seems reasonable :).

Answer (score -2):

you could turn off your wifi once you are in the game but you may only be able to play the campain

Comment: I'm pretty sure that they thought of that while building the system... Seems pretty unlikely they'll just let you have a game for free as long as you're offline.